# How can I store an enum so I can retrieve it by only identifying the variant?

Tags: rust

I have an enum like:

```
pub enum Component {
    Position { vector: [f64; 2] },
    RenderFn { render_fn: fn(Display, &mut Frame, Entity), },
}
```

I would like to store `Component`s in a hashset/hashmap where they are identified only by their enum variant (`Position` or `RenderFn`).

There can be zero or one `Position` and zero or one `RenderFn` in the collection. I would like to be able to remove/retrieve it by passing an identifier/type (`Position`/`RenderFn`).

Is there any way to do this without any ugly hacks? Perhaps enums are not the way to go?

Comment: In other ECS libraries (I assume that's what you're trying to implement!), rather than having components defined as enums, they tend to be defined as structs that `impl` a `Component` trait.

Comment: I tried this approach aswell, how would I access their data though? Since that is nothing they share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a structure, not a collection of enum variants.

```
struct Component {
    position: Option<[f64; 2]>,
    render_fn: Option<fn(Display, &mut Frame, Entity)>,
}
```

If this is likely to involve *many* kinds of components, and they mostly won't all be present, then maybe you want something like the [`typemap`](https://crates.io/crates/typemap) crate.

But to answer your question: no, a variant can't be separated from its associated values.

Comment: I clarified the question a tiny bit, an Entity (that holds the collection of components) should be able to have them added/removed to/from it.

So an Entity could have just a Position-component, or even none of them!

Comment: @Kim: Then you can use `Option`.  Or `typemap` if you're going to have many, many, many more than you've listed.

Comment: Can't see how these won't work, I'll give it a sho! ty!